# Could the diverter valve be causing water to get cold quickly?

Tags: bathroom, hot-water

I recently finished a bathroom renovation.  Went to take my first shower in the new surround and hot water only lasted about 15 mins.  For the remainder the water was lukewarm.  The new shower has a diverter valve so I'm thinking this might be where the issue is since the water remained lukewarm. Any suggestions on if this may be the problem or how to troubleshoot?

Unfortunately the surround is tiled out so I'm hoping nothing has to be ripped out.

Comment: Did the sink nearest the shower follow the same hot the lukewarm pattern as the shower? If it was the first time you had the water running for any length of time, it sounds more like something broke free inside of the hot water line and is blocking it.

Comment: Yes it did follow the same pattern.  For a bit more detail, I was showering in the guest bath while renovating.  During that time hot water in the guest bath was fine and plumbing for the new bath was already installed (including cartridges in the fixtures), we were just not using it.  That's why I'm a bit perplexed, if it were a diverter problem I would expect the same issue in the guest bath.  I'm thinking I will run the hot water in the guest bath to see what happens (e.g. does it stay hot as it did pre-new shower usage, or get lukewarm).  Maybe this will narrow down to the blockage theory?